# How to get all visits from roblox profile

Tags: lua, roblox

I wanna create roblox game (like this [game](https://www.roblox.com/games/2120256007/Check-a-Users-Last-Online-Information-More)) and me need get from profile all visits from he/she game (Place Visits). But i don't owner game. Please say how this create! (If it's unreal, say me!) Please!

Comment: How have you tried to solve this? Do you have a code sample to share? What isn't working?

Comment: Kylaaa, i use apis sites to check online player [ https://api.roblox.com/users/1/onlinestatus/ ] and more. If you know api site to check all visits from profile or function send please!
P.S If the link does not work, then the roblox servers are down (If think he real dont working, check from this site [ https://status.roblox.com ] )

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code you have tried? Or are you asking if there is a public API that exposes the information you are looking for? Have you looked at any of the [/docs endpoints](https://games.roblox.com/docs#!/Games/get_v1_games) for the games API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No possible way to receive that information from a script and I also believe the Roblox Api can't send place visits.

https://games.roblox.com/docs#!/Games/get_v1_games

You could get the visits amount of your game with universe id but it is impossible to get visits off of a user

To get a universe ID you can place ur place id below

https://api.roblox.com/universes/get-universe-containing-place?placeid=12345

This has also been asked at https://devforum.roblox.com/t/is-there-an-api-for-place-visits/629526/12